# Laravel How to update child relationship?

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I am new to laravel and fantastically stuck at saving a child table of 1:M relashtip basically I have 2 models dataset which and `table_blacklist 1 dataset` can have many `table_blacklist`

now when I trying update a value of the `table_blacklist` it gives error

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save()`

the below function is in my dataset model(parent)

```
public function updateTable($id){

    $table_blacklist = $this->table_blacklist()->find($id); //table_blacklist::find($id);
        $table_blacklist->blacklisted =true;
        $table_blacklist->save();
}
```